# How to push files from Pi to Win machine

Tags: ssh

I would like to be able to use SCP to copy files from a Pi to Win 7 machine. However, it has to work in a script running on the Pi. The problem is that I cannot establish a connection from the Pi to Win via SSH (the reverse can be done, obviously, but it's not what I need).

I read somewhere that a SSH server has to run on my windows machine to get this to work. I have WinSCP installed, is that enough? When I run in Pi command line:

```
scp filename username@192.168.0.2:C
```

I get an error

```
ssh: connect to host ... port 22: Connection refused.
```

Answer (score 1):

No version of the Windows operating system includes an SSH server as a part of its distribution. WinSCP (what you've installed) is only a client, not a server.

If you want to be able to access your Windows machine's files through SSH, you'll need to install a server. If you want access to a full bash command line, you'll need something like [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). If you just want an SFTP/FTP file server, something like [FileZilla's server](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) is probably enough.